# Enthought Canopy not syncing Python scripts

Tags: python, function, canopy

I'm using Canopy for running Python scripts on my Windows PC and facing a problem. I have my functions defined in one script and am calling those functions in another script.

My problem is that when I update and save my functions in Script 1, my other Script 2 still seems to refer to the old code.

I've tried closing both scripts and reloading them, and restarting the Canopy editor, but nothing seems to work consistently.

Has anyone encountered the same problems?

Code:

Script1.py

def foo:
  #Some code

Script2.py

import Script1
Script1.foo()

Comment: agreed and so voted

Answer (score 0):

[Jupyter / IPython: After editing a module, changes are not effective without kernel restart](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469240-Jupyter-IPython-After-editing-a-module-changes-are-not-effective-without-kernel-restart)